# Require in an abstract class that subtypes are ordered

Tags: scala

I am making a basic graph representation in Scala.

```
abstract class Vertex
class Edge (
  val source: Vertex
  val dest: Vertex
)
class Graph[V <: Vertex] {
  ...
}
```

At some point, I need to be able to sort a list of vertices in `Graph[Vertex]`.  I would like to do so by calling `vertices.sorted`.  If I make Vertex extend `Ordered[Vertex]` then I don't actually have the right `compareTo` since the ordering information is going to be data in the implemented subclass of `Vertex` and `compareTo` takes any `Vertex`.  But if I make my `Vertex` implementation `MyVertex` extend `Ordered[MyVertex]`, then that information is not available in `Graph[MyVertex]`.

What is the best solution to this problem?  Should I be using an implicit Ordering?  Is there a way to enforce that subclasses of `Vertex` have an implicit Ordering on themselves?

I would rather not do the following:

```
class MyClass extends Vertex {
  override def compare(that: Vertex) = that match {
    case that: MyClass => // do the comparison
    case _ => false
  }
}
```

Update: maybe `Graph`'s constructor needs to take an `Ordering[V]`?

Update: I could always restrict `V <: Ordered[V]` but this does not scale.  Is it possible to have multiple type restrictions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Update: maybe `Graph`'s constructor needs to take an `Ordering[V]`?

That would be my preferred approach, because this way you may pass a different `Ordering` if needed.

> Update: I could always restrict `V <: Ordered[V]` but this does not scale. Is it possible to have multiple type restrictions?

Yes, since Scala has intersection types: `V <: Ordered[V] with Something[V] with SomethingElse[V]`.

Comment: I think another problem of the latter solution is that if I have another class (say a class `Path` that represents a path through the Graph) that has the same type restriction.  And if I need to add another restriction I need to modify all these classes.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just this?

```
class Graph[V <: Vertex with Ordered[V]]
```

Or you could go the way of `Ordering` too:

```
class Graph[V <: Vertex : Ordering]
```

Comment: `: Ordering` requires `V` to have an implicit definition for an `Ordering` of `V`?  I will read up on this syntax.  I've reworked my code and it turns out that what I really need is a function to merge nodes `List(V) => V` and so far I think that an implicit parameter on the functions where this is necessary is the neatest.  Thanks for another great answer that gives me more options to consider.

Answer (score 0):

Why not design your `Graph` class to contain a `List` of `Vertex` objects? Then you can use List's handy built-in `sortWith` method.

For example:

```
class Graph(val Vertices:List[Vertex]) {
  def sorted():Graph = {
    new Graph(Vertices.sortWith((v1, v2) => { /* your comparison logic here */ }))
  }
}
```

Hope that points you in the right direction.

Comment: My vertex is a generic class and the sort definition is going to be a function of the generic subtype, not the abstract supertype, so I can't define the comparison function with `Graph`.